# How to change background tint of ViewGroup in code?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-color

I want to change background tint of `ViewGroup` in my `RecyclerView` `ViewHolder`, but it keeps throwing `NullPointerException`.

This custom made function is working for both `ImageView` and other `Views`, but it is not working for `ViewGroup` for some reason.

```
private inner class TimeViewHolder(val root: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(root){
        val minutesTv = root.findText(R.id.minutes)
        val hoursTv = root.findText(R.id.hours)

        fun bind(m: Order.Timeline, onClick: ()->Unit) {
            val a = mainActivity?:return
            with(m) {
                minutesTv.text = "%02d".format(minute)
                if (m.isClosest){
                    root.setBackgroundTint(R.color.highlight)
                } else {
                    root.setBackgroundTint(R.color.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }

fun View.setBackgroundTint(color: Int){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
        this.background.colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color), BlendMode.SRC_IN)
    } else {
        this.background.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setColorFilter(int, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Have you set a background on the `ViewGroup` somewhere? It's not going to have one by default.

Comment: Nope, that will be a problem.

Comment: if you just want to change the color of the view group you can do it by:
viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent))

Answer (score 0):

I think your context can be null in your inner TimeViewHolder class. You can get your context from viewGroup which called root as root.context and pass it in your setBackgroundTint method